Character Stuck When Colliding with Elevation and walls - Unable to Move Sideways
Here is my Setup of the Character
And here is the Setup of the Parent GameObject where my Script is and the Collider
I'm developing a third-person character in Unity and encountering several issues related to collisions and movement. The character uses a Rigidbody and a Capsule Collider for physics interactions. The movement and animation generally work fine, but I run into specific problems when dealing with steps, elevations, and walls.
Here are the issues I'm facing:
Steps and Elevations: When the character runs into steps or any elevation, it cannot jump to overcome the obstacle. The character just gets stuck at the base of the elevation.
Walls and Obstacles: When the character collides with a wall or another obstacle, it can no longer move sideways (left or right). It can only move backward, which severely limits the character's maneuverability.
I've attempted various solutions, including adjusting the friction of the Physics Material, tweaking the Rigidbody settings, and modifying the character's movement script, but these have not resolved the issues.
Here is a part of the current movement script I'm using:




private void Update() {
if(gameInput.isJumping() && isGrounded) {
Jumping();
isGrounded = false;
} else {
isGrounded = true;
}
}

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Vector2 inputVector = gameInput.GetMovementVectorNormalized();
        bool isSprinting = gameInput.isSprinting();
    
        Vector2 scaledInputVector = ScaleInputVector(inputVector, isSprinting);
    
        animator.SetFloat("horizontal", scaledInputVector.x);
        animator.SetFloat("vertical", scaledInputVector.y);
    
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(scaledInputVector.x, 0, scaledInputVector.y);
    
        if(isSprinting) {
            addForceToRigidbody(sprint, targetVelocity);
        } else {
            addForceToRigidbody(walk, targetVelocity);
        }
    }
    
    private Vector2 ScaleInputVector(Vector2 inputVector, bool isSprinting) {
        if(!isSprinting) {
            inputVector.x = Mathf.Clamp(inputVector.x, -0.5f, 0.5f);
            inputVector.y = Mathf.Clamp(inputVector.y, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        }
        return inputVector;
    }
    
    private void addForceToRigidbody(float speed, Vector3 targetVelocity) {
        targetVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity) * speed;
    
        Vector3 velocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 velocityChange = (targetVelocity - velocity);
        velocityChange.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.x, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
        velocityChange.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocityChange.z, -maxVelocityChange, maxVelocityChange);
        velocityChange.y = 0;
    
        rb.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
    
    private bool canJump() {
        bool canJump = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1.5f);
        return canJump;
    }
    
    private void Jumping() {
        rb.AddForce(0f, jump, 0f, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

}





Some things to consider: the ability to turn left AND right is dependent on the angle to which you hit the wall and the perpendicular. And "jumping" requires forward movement; you can't have that when you're right up against an object. Stop short; then take a running jump; stop; resume running. Use an "easing" function to decelerate and accelerate.

You probably need to code each leg and foot to collide with the ground.

Try to check the collision settings. The problem looks like your objects have very high friction between each other
I haven't worked in Unity for a long time, but there should be a similar setup
